# How to color SQL syntax in IntelliJ console?

Tags: intellij-idea

In one course I saw this SQL Syntax highlighting. How to do it in IntelliJ ultimate? Is this some kind of plugin or embedded function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [SQL Dialect](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-languages-sql-dialects.html) and/or [SQL Resolution scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/settings-languages-sql-resolution-scopes.html) for your project.
Also if you have added a [data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.3/connecting-to-a-database.html) to project, hit SHIFT twice, find action 'Attach session' and select desired variant.

Comment: I just try it and still the same.

Comment: @MrFisherman highlighting will work only for SQL injections, so it should be some code like PHP: $var="SELECT * FROM t". Your example looks like a piece of text log which can't be recognized as any known language.